# Memory leak detection using "Microsoft Debugging Tools for Windows"

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2008

We got a trouble with memory leak detection.
We have an application developed using Visual Studio C++ 2008.
A memory leak has been detected in the application.
We can see this memory leak in Task Manager.
The leak is also detected automatically using an external monitoring script (written for Microsoft Script Host, cscript.exe).
Both amounts of leaked memory are identical.

From the script, we use WMI ActiveX to request information about process memory:

```
var wmi  = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
….
select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process where Name like '"+processName+"%'
….
```

---

We analyzed these properties of class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process:
PrivateBytes
WorkingSet

Within our application, in order to find memory leaking allocations we use Microsoft Debugging Tool.
First, we configure gflags + umdh:
gflags /i process.exe +ust -hpc –hfc

Then we create stacktrace logs. We do it periodically while application is running:

```
umdh.exe –p:%pid% > log1
umdh.exe –p:%pid% > log2
…
umdh.exe –p:%pid% > logN
```

When stacktrace information is accumulated, we make reports using the following commands:

```
umdh.exe  -d  log1  log2  > cmp1-2
umdh.exe  -d  log2  log3  > cmp2-3
```

Usually, we can detect allocation problems using this technique, and then can eliminate them.
This toolkit helped us to find some real memory leaks.
After all the leaks found by this technique were eliminated, we can see a stable amount of memory used by our application
on our test PCs.

But after the release of our application has been issued, we saw memory leaks again, on some of our client’s PCs.
We detected it remotely by WMI ActiveX tool described before.
Then we requested a full OS image from our clients and reproduced memory leaks on this image.
We saw continuous growth of memory used by our process (~50Mb over 24 hours)
Then we tried gflags+umdh on this OS image but could not see any additional memory leaks.

Here are the questions:

1. Why can amounts of leaked memory reported by WMI request and by MS Debugging Tool differ?
2. What additional techniques can we try to detect memory leaks?
3. Maybe, we should set some additional flags in gflags? If yes, what are these flags?

Comment: Growth in memory consumption is not a sufficient metric to unambiguously determine the existence of a memory leak. Due to the fact that in C++ objects are pinned to a specific location in memory for the entire lifetime heap fragmentation is a real issue. Heap fragmentation can manifest itself in the same observable way as a genuine resource leak would.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the tools used (Task Manager etc) measure memory consumption. An increase in memory consumption can be caused by a direct memory leak (`new` without `delete`), but also by an indirect leak.

The latter form happens when you have allocated memory, stopped using that memory, and still have the theoretical ability to deallocate it, but your program would only do so on shutdown. The OS doesn't know the fine details of your program, so it can't differentiate between the two cases.